# How to receive raw postgres answer in php

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a query:

```
pg_query("
INSERT INTO all_types (type) VALUES('something1')
RETURNING id;
");
```

How can I receive the answer from postgres whatever it is? In this case, I want to receive last id. Once I perform this query in Adminer, I get the answer with id, but I don't know how to get in in PHP code.

Comment: what have you tried before asking SO?

Comment: If only there were documentation for `pg_query`, like www.php.net/pg_query - and if ONLY it had copy paste examples on how to use it... if only.

Comment: as I see in docummentation. pg_query can show only error or results with rows, but on insert I don't need any rows answer?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I tried to do `echo` and `var_dump` for this function. Echo gives Resource id #4.
I'm new to raw sql queries writing for postgres, so not sure what commands to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `pg_fetch_result`. It will be something like:

```
$resource = pg_query($connection, "INSERT INTO all_types (type) VALUES('something1') RETURNING id;");
$result = pg_fetch_result($resource);
```

Additionally `pg_query` takes 2 parameters: first is connection to your db, which isn't present in your example.

Comment: how to echo variable $results? I get nothing :(

Comment: try to not use `echo` or `print_r` to display variables (for debug) - it shows nothing for `null` or `false` values. Use `var_dump` instead - it additionaly shows you type of variable.
I've edited my answer - I didn't saw that there is no `$connection` parameter to `pg_query` function - it may be main problem.

Comment: I added the connection. Query inserts a new row, but still I get an answer `NULL`, even with `var_dump`

Comment: Try to paste Your query in some client (pg_admin or something like that) - does it return expected value? Maybe problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, it has returned the `id` number

Comment: According to documentation `pg_fetch_result` will return `null` if database returns `null` and will return `false` in case of errors. You can try to additionally debug with `$state = pg_result_status($resource);`.